# getCurrentUser() functions error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
currentFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
```

this code works with all get functions when auth with google but when auth with facebook i get nullPointerException.
i check for user using this code

```
 if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        goToLoginScreen();
    }
    else{
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like there is no current user, so then you're calling `null.getDisplayName()` which throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) says that it will, in fact, return null if there is no current user (there is no one logged in).  You should always fully expect this case to be a possibility.

If you want to know as soon as possible if there is a user logged in, you should instead use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) to check for a login event by calling getCurrentUser() in its onAuthStateChanged() to see if it returns non-null.